# insert maximum selected value as new record oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

i'm using oracle DB . and i'm trying to select max number from table and then increment it by one then re-insert it as new record for example:
              `insert into table1(id,name) values (select max(id) from table1 + 1,'name2');`

but it gave me missing expression error.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 19):

```
INSERT INTO table1( id, name )
  SELECT max(id) + 1, 'name2'
    FROM table1
```

will be valid syntax.  This method of generating `id` values, is a very poor approach.  It does not work in a multi-user environment since many different sessions may get the same `id` value.  It is also much less efficient than using a sequence.

Comment: *many different sessions may get the same id*  +1. Very important point.

Answer (score 6):

```
insert into table1(id,name) values ( (select max(id) from table1 ) + 1,'name2')
```

Answer (score 1):

While insert into table by selecting, there is no need for keyword `values`

```
insert into table1(id,name) (select max(id) from table1 + 1,'name2');
```